# button onclick() alternative using jquery or mvc3 actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a better (more up to date) alternative to the following standard onbuttonclick() call to a javascript function using jquery or mvc3 helper actions?

```
<button onclick="javascript:AddNew()" title="ad action">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using JQuery...

```
<button id="buttonID" title="ad action">Add</button> 

$('#buttonID').click(function() {
  alert('click called.');
});
```

Comment: Why not just put her `AddNew()` right where it needs to be for even more clarity? It's fewer characters than your alert, even. ;-)

Comment: @GregPettit I'm new to jquery world. Could you give an example of what you are suggestion?

Comment: @nam , My comment was just that her example has a very short method call, `AddNew`. Could have just used that. `$('#buttonID').click(function() { AddNew(); });`

Comment: @GregPettit I see now. At first, I thought you meant that one can add a jquery function to onClick attribute of a button - like the following one for javasctipt: `<input type="button" onclick="javascript: alert(`TEST`)" title="Test1" />`. But, now I understand, that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

For a particular button, use StressChicken's answer.  For the more general case, where you want to handle any button belonging to a certain class—or matching any selector for that matter—see jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.  Note that this will also work with dynamically added content.

```
$(document).on("click", ".selectorClass", function() {
  alert('click called.');
});
```

Note that this function requires jQuery 1.7

Comment: I wouldn't set `document` as the listener, but rather the nearest permanent ancestor. `.on()` can also be used for self-listeners, so I prefer it anyhow; the syntax is nicer.

Comment: @Greg - why would you not use `document`?  I've seen a lot of code samples doing that.  Is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: it works out exactly the same as using `.live()` which a lot of samples also use (I would say it's the most popular binding function for SO jQuery samples despite being well-documented as a poor performer). The reason is simple: for every click, the entire document needs to be checked for a match. If you delegate listening to a more nested ancestor (one that's not destroyed during other DOM operations) you can greatly narrow the number of elements that are checked when the event is fired. It's a performance thing. Though I also like the elegance of it.

Comment: @Greg - for sure, you should always use the most narrow ancestor you can get away with.  But for situations where you want to handle clicks coming from **anywhere**, which selector should you use?  $("body").on(...)?

Comment: It seems we agree. ;-) I guess since the answer was only supplying 'document' without a caveat, I assumed that you tend to stick to the quasi-`live` usage. For *anywhere* clicks... I doubt there's much performance difference between document and body. Usually there's at least a wrapper div that can be used (eliminating headers, footers, and sidebars from the equation).

Answer (score 1):

when the button more than one we could add some class to them and just add some line of code to call them one by one, like

```
<button class="mybtn">I'm Clikced 1</button>
<button class="mybtn">I'm Clikced 2</button>
<button class="mybtn">I'm Clikced 3</button>
<button class="mybtn">I'm Clikced 4</button>
```

and Jquery look like this

```
$(function(){
  $("button.mybtn").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).text();
     alert(value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery it would be better.

Add

$('#button').click(function() {
  alert('Function called.');
});